# how put a class in a span inside of link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
 <%= link_to content_tag(:span, :class => "ava-icon") %>
```

I'm trying to put in a class of the span on a link. I've tried this method and others without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of content_tag is the contents of the tag. If you just want an empty span tag then:

```
content_tag :span, nil, :class => 'ava-icon'
# "<span class="ava-icon"></span>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're just passing the option through to the wrong thing:

```
link_to(content_tag(:span, :class => 'x'))
# => <a><span class="x"></span></a>

link_to(content_tag(:span), :class => 'x')
# => <a class="x"><span></span></a>
```

Presumably you also want to have a destination for your link.

Comment: thank you very much for your help tadman but i have no idea why the sill rendering this on html: <a href="/"><span>{:class=&gt;&quot;ava-icon&quot;}</span></a>